# C++ linking of binary libraries or simple header inclusion?

Tags: c++, header-files

I am currently compiling the binaries for the great booster package [it seems to be, because I can include the great lambda functions :)]. Now I have two options:

1) Compile all the libraries and link these libraries into my project or
2) Just add the header files and compile the overall project.

Well, it's a basic question for comprehension: When should I favor option 1 over option 2? Is this a compile time quesion?

Sorry I know this question is really basic but I'm not really sure how to value these alternatives.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Boost is not a library, it is a collection of libraries. Some of those libraries are header-only and don't need linking, others aren't. There are no "alternatives" here, since you need to do different things depending on the library in question.

Comment: hmmm, I used the term "package" for this library collection. I know that I have to implement only the particular library I really need. Currently I am compiling >1Gb of libraries with help of the bjam tool. So does this mean: This is only obligatory for a small subset of libraries?

Comment: On the boost web-site, read the [getting started page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries).

Comment: If you invoke `b2 --show-libraries` (`bjam` rather than `b2` for older versions of Boost), it will tell you exactly which ones require building (i.e., are not header-only). In Boost 1.48, there are only 21 such libraries. If you're using all of them then build all of them; otherwise, build only the ones you need.

Answer (score 0):

Only some of boost actually requires compiled libraries (and not, IMO, the more useful parts). For most of it, just include the header(s) which implement the functionality you are looking for. Check [the library listing](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/) to see what is available; if it needs a compiled portion, it will say something other than "Header only" under "Build & Link." If you are developing on Linux, boost's libraries should be available and easily accessible for linkage without any building on your part, since they are used in many Linux applications.